# How to do an Integer.parseInt() for a decimal number?

Tags: java, parsing, integer

The Java code is as follows:

```
String s = "0.01";
int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

However this is throwing a NumberFormatException... What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

0.01 is not an integer (whole number), so you of course can't parse it as one. Use `Double.parseDouble` or `Float.parseFloat` instead.

Answer (score 114):

```
String s = "0.01";
double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
int i = (int) d;
```

The reason for the exception is that an integer does not hold rational numbers (= basically fractions). So, trying to parse `0.3` to a int is nonsense.
A `double` or a `float` datatype can hold rational numbers.

The way Java casts a `double` to an `int` is done by *removing the part after the decimal separator by rounding towards zero*.

```
int i = (int) 0.9999;
```

`i` will be zero.

Comment: Your cast will completely lose the fractional information. I'm not sure that's a good idea to advise.

Comment: Ok! maybe I will have to do something like this Double d = Double.parseDouble(s); right?

Comment: @Kevin: yes, but you can use also 'double' instead of 'Double'

Comment: He says he wants an integer, but are we sure that's what he *needs*?

Answer (score 33):

Use,

```
String s="0.01";
int i= new Double(s).intValue();
```

Answer (score 21):

```
String s="0.01";
int i = Double.valueOf(s).intValue();
```

Answer (score 9):

This kind of conversion is actually suprisingly unintuitive in Java

Take for example a following string : "100.00"

**C : a simple standard library function at least since 1971** ([Where did the name `atoi` come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909768/where-did-the-name-atoi-come-from))

```
int i = atoi(decimalstring);
```

**Java : mandatory passage by Double (or Float) parse, followed by a cast**

```
int i = (int)Double.parseDouble(decimalstring);
```

Java sure has some oddities up it's sleeve

Comment: C simply ignore the rest of the string, and parse whatever it can parse (in this case, it is `100`). There is no way for you to know whether `atoi` actually parsed everything in the string or not, whether the string contains number or whether the number overflows the type. `strtol` is an better alternative where all the things above can be detected. Java is stricter, but it makes sure that all those cases are covered.

Comment: I agree with Raywell because this works `Double.valueOf("16543").intValue();` So Java wants to be a PITA when you want to quickly convert to int, yet Double is a lot more general.

Answer (score 4):

Using BigDecimal to get rounding:

```
String s1="0.01";
int i1 = new BigDecimal(s1).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).intValueExact();

String s2="0.5";
int i2 = new BigDecimal(s2).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).intValueExact();
```

Answer (score 3):

> suppose we take a integer in string.
>
> String s="100";
>       int i=Integer.parseInt(s);
>       or
>       int i=Integer.valueOf(s);
>
> but in your question the number you are trying to do the change is the whole number
>
> String s="10.00";
>
> double d=Double.parseDouble(s);
>
> int i=(int)d;

This way you get the answer of the value which you are trying to get it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Double.parseDouble(String a)` what you are looking for is not an integer as it is  not a whole number.

Answer (score 2):

use this one

`int number = (int) Double.parseDouble(s);`

Answer (score 2):

One more solution is possible.

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(new DecimalFormat("#").format(decimalNumber))
```

Example:

```
Integer.parseInt(new DecimalFormat("#").format(Double.parseDouble("010.021")))
```

Output

```
10
```