# What does "itoa" stand for in strconv.Itoa?

Tags: go, itoa

This might sound like a silly question... But I can't find anywhere what the "a" in strconv.Itoa actually stands for. If its taking an integer and turning it into a string, why isn't the function called Itos?

Comment: it stands for `i`nteger `to` `a`scii: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909768/where-did-the-name-atoi-come-from

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**integer to ASCII**. It comes from the C language/UNIX. See this thread for more: [Where did the name `atoi` come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909768/where-did-the-name-atoi-come-from)

In the C language, there is no concept such as strings, you have arrays of characters that are null terminated.

Thanks to @mvp!

Comment: Also, it's called `itoa` because the precedent set by C to use that name for this kind of conversion.

Comment: Was editing my comment to add that, when I noticed it was tagged Go. Thanks!

Comment: this is wrong. `A` is coming from `ASCII`, not from array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909768/where-did-the-name-atoi-come-from

Comment: The guys who developed Go at Google, also wrote most of Unix and Plan9.  So there are many other Unix references littered throughout the documentation.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense. It's historical baggage that the Go apis have mostly abandoned - but not in this case. Despite UTF8 adoption growing, ASCII is not yet dead, alas.