# converting a string (containing numbers) into an integer and returning that integer

Tags: c++, arrays, string

i'm working on a code right now in C++, in which i'm supposed to make a function which receives a string of numbers and converts it into an integer then returns that value. for example if i pass "4569" as string, it will return 4569 integer value.
can anyone help me point out where i'm wrong ??? thanks in advance :)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void getInput(char arr[] , int size )
{
    cout<<"ENTER THE ARRAY"<<endl;
    cin.getline(arr,size);

}

int stringToInteger(char source[])
{
    int sum = 0;
    int y=strlen(source);
    int multiply = 1;
    for( int i=y ; i>=0 ; i--)
    {
        int n= source[i];
        sum = (sum + (n * multiply));
        multiply = (multiply *10);
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    const int size =100;
    char inputArr [size];
    getInput (inputArr, size );

    int x = stringToInteger (inputArr );
    cout<<"THE RETURNED INTEGER VALUE IS"<<endl;
    cout<<x<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start from `strlen(source)-1`

Comment: And subtract `'0'` from `source[i]`. `'5' != 5`, but `'5'-'0' = 5`.

Comment: I think you also need to deal with overflow problem

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: why not use stoi (c++11), atoi, or stringstream? the method -'0' is not portable in systems where ascii is not used...

Comment: @elvis.dukaj: `- '0'` is always portable.  The C++ specification requires that the digits are contiguous in the character set.  "In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous."

Answer (score 2):

First, you're starting at the character after the end of the string. If the length (returned by `strlen`) is `y`, then valid indexes are `0 <= i < y`. So your loop wants to start from `y-1`.

```
for( int i=y-1 ; i>=0 ; i--)
            ^^
```

Then, you need to convert each ASCII digit into a value from 0 to 9, by subtracting the ASCII value for '0':

```
int n= source[i] - '0';
                 ^^^^^
```

Then you should probably detect and handle erroneous input, including values that are too large to be represented by `int`.

Then, once you've learnt how to implement this in C, throw it away and use the C++ library:

```
std::string input;
std::getline(std::cin, input);
int x = std::stoi(input);
```

Comment: The `atoi` function has been a part of the standard __C__ library for at least 20 years.

Comment: I thought `atoi` is deprecated nowadays in favor of `strol`?

Comment: @SteveBarnes: Indeed, if you don't care about error handling. But what's that got to do with a question about C++ (even if it is mistagged with C, and written with C idioms)?

Comment: Don't know about the C library but I remember using atoi in 1979.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909768/where-did-the-name-atoi-come-from says it was in the 1971 Unix (but not C) manual.

Comment: A left-to-right implementation is better than doing `strlen` at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

and in your `main()`:

```
int x = atoi(inputArr);
```

Comment: In C++, that should be `<cstdlib>` and `std::atoi`. Direct use of C library headers is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you aren't using `atoi` or `std::stoi`, but your algorithm has a logical flaw:

```
int stringToInteger(char source[])
{
    int sum = 0;
    int y=strlen(source);
    int multiply = 1;
    for(int i=y - 1; i >= 0; i--) // you were starting at y, which is 1 passed the end of the array
    {
        int n = (int)(source[i] - '0');
        sum += (n * multiply); // += makes this more readable
        multiply *= 10; // same with  *=
    }
    return sum;
}
```

That said, if this was something other than a homework assignment, you should be using the solutions posted https://stackoverflow.com/a/18238566/529761 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/18238682/529761 (depending on your language requirements).

Also, even this change has 1 potential problem:  If the `source` contains non-numeric characters, it will not work properly.  A simple way to approach it is to break out if you encounter a character that shouldn't be there:

```
int stringToInteger(char source[])
{
    int sum = 0;
    int y=strlen(source);
    int multiply = 1;
    for(int i=y - 1; i >= 0; i--) // you were starting at y, which is 1 passed the end of the array
    {
        int n = (int)(source[i] - '0');
        if (n < 0 || n > 9)
            break;
        sum += (n * multiply); // += makes this more readable
        multiply *= 10; // same with  *=
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing ASCII-specific about doing `- '0'`.

Comment: You are correct.  I meant to remove that comment prior to posting.  The edit will do so.

Answer (score 0):

No need to call a `strlen` -- until you are allowed to use library functions (the above-mentioned `atoi` and `strtol`), you can use this:

```
int stringToInteger(char *source)
{
  int sum = 0;
  if (source)
    while (*source >= '0' && *source <= '9')
    {
      sum = 10*sum + *source - '0';
      source++;
    }
  return sum;
}
```

As implied in about every other answer, you forgot there is a difference between the ASCII character '0' and the binary value `0`.