# Integer.parseInt and string format with decimal number

Tags: java

i try to convert string value into int.
THe string value contain a decimal number, but i don't manage to convert this value in int format.

I've write this code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args){

    System.out.println("Test");
    final String nombre = "3.0";
    int entier;
    entier=Integer.parseInt(nombre);
    try
    {
        System.out.println("result :" + Integer.parseInt(nombre));
    }
    catch(final NumberFormatException nfe){
        System.out.println("NumberFormatException: "+nfe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I have no result.
Thank in advance for your help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450991/how-to-do-an-integer-parseint-for-a-decimal-number?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description I understood that you want to print an int. You can code it like this:

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws ParseException {
            NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance();
            formatter.setParseIntegerOnly(true);
            System.out.println("Test");
            final String nombre = "3.0";
            int entier;
            entier=formatter.parse(nombre).intValue();
            System.out.println("result :" + entier);
        }
```

NumberFormat will do the job

Answer (score 3):

As it is a floating point number in your string so use `Float.parseFloat` or `Double.parseDouble` instead of `Integer.parseInt`

Answer (score 2):

Your `String` is a `Double` and not `Integer`.

```
         try
         {
             System.out.println("result :" + Float.parseFloat(nombre));
              // OR
             System.out.println("result :" + Double.parseDouble(nombre));
         }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can still use the same input. try

```
  System.out.println("result :" + new Double(nombre).intValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but this is a working piece of your code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args){

    System.out.println("Test");
    final String nombre = "3.0";
    float entier;
    entier=Float.parseFloat(nombre);
    try
    {
        System.out.println("result :" + Float.parseFloat(nombre));
    }
    catch(final NumberFormatException nfe){
        System.out.println("NumberFormatException: "+nfe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Bottomline: use Float.parseFloat or Double.parseDouble