# Convert String which is "float" to Integer

Tags: kotlin

How to convert a string value which contains float representation to integer in `kotlin`?

I tried to convert string to float with `.toFloat()` and then converted it to an integer using `toInt()` and it works flawlessly.
But how to convert such string to integer directly?

```
val strDemo = "42.22"
val intDemo = strDemo.toInt()
```

snippet above throws `NumberFormatException` because it is not correct number representaion of Integer.

But, when I try

```
val strDemo = "42.22"
val intDemo = strDemo.toFloat().toInt()
```

it converts the data with no exception because string gets converted to float first. And there is a correct number representation for a Float value.

Now how to bypass the `toFloat()` method and convert `strDemo` to `Integer` directly?

Comment: You can not because `42.22` is not an integer . It has to be done this way .. At simplest `strDemo.toFloat().toInt()`.. Either you get first subString which is also hectic ... See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450991/how-to-do-an-integer-parseint-for-a-decimal-number.

Comment: you can remove the values after "." and then tries to parse it as int

Comment: That is what I thought before posting this question, But I thought there could be a way to directly convert a string which represents a float to integer. Thanks for your comment @ADM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no magic function that will convert a decimal/float string numbers to integer directly. It has to be done this way. Even if you found one, I'm sure that the process `toFloat().toInt()` still happen on that function.

So the solution that you can do is to create an extension of `String` like this:

**StringExt.kt**

```
fun String.floatToInt(): Int {
    return this.toFloat().toInt()
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
val strDemo = "42.22"
val intDemo = strDemo.floatToInt()
```

Comment: Yes, I can always create an extension method to do float to integer conversion but it will be redundant as there is already a way I can do it with ```.toFloat().toInt()```. Thanks for your answer and tip.